# #1216909923: The argument "multimedia" does not exist. (More information) Typo3

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I have a form for updating an entity. When I  try to call `updateAction()`, it returns an error. What is the reason? How can I resolve the issue?

form.html:

```
<f:form action="update" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="multimedia"  object="{multimedia}" id="multimediaEditForm">
          <f:render partial="Multimedia/FormFields" arguments="{_all}" />
</f:form>
```

updateAction:

```
/**
 * Setting TypeConverter option for file upload
 */
public function initializeUpdateAction()
{

    $this->setTypeConverterConfiguration('multimedia');
}

/**
 * action update
 *
 * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Validate("PITS\RccMultimedia\Domain\Validator\MultimediaValidator", param="$multimedia")
 * @return void
 */
public function updateAction()
{
    $updatedBy = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user ;
    $userObject = $this->userRepository->findByUid($updatedBy['uid']);

    $multimedia = $this->request->getArgument('multimedia');
}

/**
* For mapping properties to object
*/
protected function setTypeConverterConfiguration($argument)
{
    $uploadConfiguration = array(
            UploadedFileReferenceConverter::CONFIGURATION_ALLOWED_FILE_EXTENSIONS => 'jpg,jpeg,html,css,html,png,bmp,txt,doc,docx,xlf,ico,gif,ogg,tiff,mp4,wmv,webm,movie,pdf',
            UploadedFileReferenceConverter::CONFIGURATION_UPLOAD_FOLDER => 'fileadmin/user_upload',
    );
    /** @var PropertyMappingConfiguration $newFileConfiguration */
    $newFileConfiguration = $this->arguments[$argument]->getPropertyMappingConfiguration();
    $newFileConfiguration->forProperty('multimediaFile')->setTypeConverterOptions('Vendor\\Multimedia\\Property\\TypeConverter\\UploadedFileReferenceConverter', $uploadConfiguration);
}
```

`$this->arguments` returns empty but  `$this->request->getArgument('multimedia');` has the value.

Answer (score 0):

You must add an argument to your `updateAction()`, otherwise data is only available in the web request as you have noticed:

```
/**
 * action update
 */
public function updateAction(Multimedia $multimedia)
{
    // ...
}
```

Here your `Multimedia` model is directly used and thus conveniently available in your action. Also notice that the explicit validator mention can be dropped since [domain model validators](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/2-validating-domain-objects.html#validating-in-the-domain-model-with-an-own-validator-class) are automatically added.